# Como converter uma std::string em uma QString?

Tags: c++, string, qt, conversão-de-tipo

Estou tentando fazer uma simples caixa de diálogo exibir meu nome. Vejam o código.

```
 Pessoa *p = new Pessoa("Ronald Araújo", "ronald.araujo@live.com", 23);

 QMessageBox msg;
 msg.setText(QString::fromUtf8(p->getNome()));
 msg.exec();
```

Porém o código quebra na linha do setText() com o seguinte erro:

> error: no matching function for call to
>   'QString::fromUtf8(std::string)'
>   msg.setText(QString::fromUtf8(p->getNome));

Lembrando que quando eu coloco por exemplo msg.setText(QString::fromUtf8("Oi mundo")) o código roda normalmente.

Implementação para retornar o nome:

```
string Pessoa::getNome(){   return this->nome; }
```

Alguém pode me dar uma luz?

Comment: Apenas para confirmar, você adicionou o #include <QString> ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Primeira solução:

```
 Pessoa *p = new Pessoa("Ronald Araújo", "ronald.araujo@live.com", 23);

 QMessageBox msg;
 msg.setText(QString::fromStdString(p->getNome()));
 msg.exec();
```

## Segunda solução:

Mude a definição de `Pessoa`.

```
QString Pessoa::getNome() { return this->nome; }
```

Desde que, é claro, mude o `Pessoa::nome` para `QString` também.

Normalmente uma aplicação feita para a Qt é preferível usar os tipos da Qt. Claro que há situações que isto não é possível, daí a primeira solução é a ideal.

Aí você poderá usar:

```
 Pessoa *p = new Pessoa("Ronald Araújo", "ronald.araujo@live.com", 23);

 QMessageBox msg;
 msg.setText(p->getNome());
 msg.exec();
```

Evidentemente que nesta solução, você vai ter que garantir que tenha uma sobrecarga do  construtor que faça a conversão de `std::string` para `QString`. Algo como:

```
Pessoa(string nome, string email, int idade) {
    this.nome = nomeQString::fromStdString(nome);
    this.email = nomeQString::fromStdString(email);
    this.idade = idade;
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura.](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/String/QString.cpp)

Comment: Perfeito! Muito obrigado. Utilizei a primeira solução mesmo. :)

Answer (score -1):

Utilizando da mesma dúvida consegui resolver um problema de conversão de string.

```
void MainWindow::on_HashButton_clicked()
{

    QString msg = ui->lineEdit->text();  // msg RECEBE IFNORMAÇÃO DIGITADA EM lineEdit

    /*antes*/
    // ui->label=>setText(s->sha1(msg.toStdstring())); // no matching function 
    //for call


    ui->label->setText(QString::fromStdString(s->sha1(msg.toStdString()))); // mostra resultado do metodo sha1 em label

}
```